# Azure Pipeline is triggered even when branch is excluded

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have the below pipeline which extends the template. I also have a policy on the target branch (dev) with another pipeline triggered on PR.

My problem is that this pipeline also triggers on PR, meaning that it triggers on feat/*. Is there a way to exclude that?

**Pipeline:**

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - src/Services/TestServices
    - src/BuildingBlocks/HealthChecks
    - src/BuildingBlocks/Monitoring
    - src/BuildingBlocks/Common
    - src/BuildingBlocks/MessagingBus

resources:
- repo: self

extends:
  template: '/src/buildTemplate.yml'
```

**Template:**

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - main
     - dev
   exclude:
     - '*'
 paths:
  exclude:
  - README.md
  - .gitignore
  - '**/appsettings.Development.json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this doc about [Pipeline CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

> If you use templates to author YAML files, then you can only specify triggers in the main YAML file for the pipeline. You cannot specify triggers in the template files.

We are not able to set the Pipeline trigger in the YAML template.

In your case, although the Pipeline runs successfully, it ignores the set Pipeline CI trigger branch. So the feat/* branch can also trigger the pipeline.

You can change to set the CI trigger to Main YAML and check if it can work.

For example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
   include:
   - main
   - dev
   exclude:
   - '*'

  paths:
    include:
    - src/Services/TestServices
    - src/BuildingBlocks/HealthChecks
    - src/BuildingBlocks/Monitoring
    - src/BuildingBlocks/Common
    - src/BuildingBlocks/MessagingBus

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
- repo: self

...
```